# JavaFX is possible to enable scrolling with hidden scrollbar?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar

I am creating a simple `VBox` wrapped into a `ScrollPane`.
I tried something like:

Into CSS

```css
.scroll-bar{ 
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Into the controller:

```
Set<Node> nodes = scroller.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
for (final Node node : nodes) {
    if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
        ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar) node;
        sb.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I tried also to style the scrollbar in other ways (also assign the class "edge-to-edge") but when the scrollbar is not needed (as default policy) I can see the space that should be occupied by the scrollbar. 
 My goal is to maintain the `VBox` scrollable, but I want to completely hide the scrollbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `vbarPolicy` to `NEVER`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        vbox.getChildren().add(new Text(Integer.toString(i)));
    }

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vbox);
    scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER); // never show a vertical ScrollBar
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true); // set content width to viewport width
    scrollPane.setPannable(true); // allow scrolling via mouse dragging

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 300, 200));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried to use the vbarpolicy, but the real solution is setPannable in my case. thank you very much again