# JavaFX - How to hide scrollbar from TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx, chat, fxml, scenebuilder

can anyone tell me how to hide the scrollbar without disabeling it?

I'm writing a chatsystem and has core features working but when ever the chat fills out the textarea the scrollbar apprears in order to make room further down but I can't seem to find a way to hide the scrollbar without disabeling it completely.

Otherwise if it would be possible to just change the opacity to make it less visible without changing the opacity of the chat itself.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206692/javafx-textarea-hiding-scroll-bars

Comment: It gives a nullPonter when trying to initialize the scrollBarv.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the relevant excerpts of your code, as well as the stack trace where you get the NPE.

Comment: There is not really anything else than the nullpointer when I put the solution from the other question in the initializer of the FX controller.

Could it be related to the fact that the textarea doesn't activate the scrollbar untill the area is filled with more text than it can hold with the given size?

Comment: Without knowing which line is causing the NPE nobody can help you.

Comment: ScrollBar scrollBarv = (ScrollBar) txtArea_Chat.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical"); gives NPE when in the FX initializer

Comment: Have a look on the [fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641171/4629012).

Answer (score 2):

Use a CSS stylesheet. As shown in [this section](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area) of the *JavaFX CSS Reference Guide*, a `TextArea` has a `ScrollPane` as part of its substructure. If you go to the `ScrollPane` [section](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area) you'll see two available CSS properties: `-fx-hbar-policy` and `-fx-vbar-policy`. These relate to the [`ScrollPane.hbarPolicy`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#hbarPolicyProperty) and [`ScrollPane.vbarPolicy`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vbarPolicyProperty) properties, respectively.

To never show either scroll bar, use the following:

```css
.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-hbar-policy: NEVER;
    -fx-vbar-policy: NEVER;
}
```

Then add the stylesheet to your scene.